# How to export nothing from a js file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

I want to export nothing from a js file.
And import this nothing to another file

like that :
export.js

```js
Array.proptotye.a = 'a';
export;
```

import.js

```js
import from 'export.js'
console.log([].a)
```

And i want it to **console log 'a'**

Comment: That's pretty easy: if you need to export nothing, you do not export and if you need to import nothing, you do not import. Jokes aside, it is very likely that you are thinking to your problem in the wrong way; can you provide a bit more context? What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that modifying `prototype` objects with non-standard features is considered very bad practice.

Comment: @loganfsmyth i used **Object.defineProperty** is that ok or is there a better solution

Comment: @secan I'm trying to extend a prototye of a native class, and then i want to access it with every js code that i use.

Comment: @AxelAMGHAR Instead of adding a function to the prototype, you should write your code with individual modules (CommonJS or ESM), like Node/Webpack-written code does, and then put your helper function in a module, and import into other modules where you want to use that function.

Comment: @loganfsmyth but what if want that function to be accesbile everywhere and only on string variables so 'xxx'.capitalize() works but not [].capitalize()

Comment: If you want it accessible everywhere, ideally you'd import it everywhere, but otherwise I'd just make the function a normal global function. If you want it only on strings, then don't pass it something that isn't a string, and potentially add an `if(typeof arg !== "string") throw new Error();` to the top of the function to help you catch errors. Your existing code would just throw `undefined` is not a function which is even less useful in my opinion.

Comment: @loganfsmyth you're telling me that creating global methods everywhere is a bad practice in js. Why is laravel using helpers ? Are they doing a bad thing according to you? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#introduction

Comment: That's actually a good example of what you could do. That code for instance isn't doing `$array->accessible()`, it instead imports the `Arr` namespace, and calls `Arr::accessible($array)`. In JS in your case you'd make `array-helpers.js` and depending on which module system you want to use, you do `export function accessible(arr) { }` or `exports.accessible = function(arr) { }` and then import functions from `array-helpers.js` in other files so you can pull in functions from that file. https://www.codemag.com/Article/1709061/Introduction-to-Node-Modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules don't have to have an `export` statement. Just have none:

```
Array.proptotye.a = 'a';
```

You can load a module without importing anything from it with this syntax:

```
import './export.js';
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you inspired by [nocode](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/nocode) ? xD

What do you mean by "import nothing"? --> if you need nothing, just don't import it

Comment: Yes it wasent so clear, i added specification on the post of why i want to export nothing but still need it